# Custom header titles gives duplicate column definition name provided

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material Table and I want to change the header name in the table.

So I created an array for the columns:

```
columnsToDisplay = [{"display": "name", "name": "Name"}, {"display": "something", "name": "Something here"}]
```

I then thought I could go through this with:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.name}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

But then I get this error:

```
Duplicate column definition name provided: "[object Object]".
```

Comment: seems that you need to change the name for `let column` to `let newname`

Comment: matColumnDef="{{column}}" transforms the column into a string ([object Object]) and passes that string as the matColumnDef input. You probably want to pass the column object itself: [matColumnDef]="column", or maybe the name of the column:  [matColumnDef]="column.name"

Comment: Can you please show me how because I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution you can do this for example like this:

```
  columns = [{'column': 'name', 'title': 'Name'}, {'column': 'environment', 'title': 'Environment'}]
```

in the html you need to change this:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.column}}" *ngFor="let column of columns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.title}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
```

I supouse you can make some like

```
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
        {{element[column.name]}} //<!--show the property "column.name"
    </td>
```